# CXF Bus - Add HttpConduitFeature with custom timeouts

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I am trying to configure the CXF Bus, with common timeouts for all clients. For that, I am using HttpConduitFeature and adding it to the Bus during the initial configuration as below:

```
@Configuration
public class CxfContext {

    @Autowired
    private SoapConfigurations soapConfigurations;

    @Bean
    public Bus bus() {

        SpringBus b = new SpringBus();

        List<Feature> features = ImmutableList.<Feature> builder() //
            .add(loggingFeature()) //
            .add(conduitFeature()) //
            .build();

        b.setFeatures(features);
        return b;
    }

    private LoggingFeature loggingFeature() {
        LoggingFeature f = new LoggingFeature();
        f.setPrettyLogging(true);
        f.setVerbose(true);
        f.setLimit(-1);
        return f;
    }

    private HttpConduitFeature conduitFeature() {

        HttpConduitFeature feature = new HttpConduitFeature();

        HttpConduitConfig conduitConfig = new HttpConduitConfig();

        HTTPClientPolicy clientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        clientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(10000);
        clientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(10000);

        conduitConfig.setClientPolicy(clientPolicy);

        feature.setConduitConfig(conduitConfig);

        return feature;
    }

}
```

After, when generating the Soap client, I am using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean and setting the Bus to it:

```
@Configuration
public class SoapClientContext {

    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    @Bean
    public IService myService(SoapConfigurations soapConfigurations) {

        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

        factory.setAddress(soapConfigurations.getUrl());
        factory.setBus(bus);

        return factory.create(IService.class);
    }

}
```

The client is using correctly the logging feature configured in the Bus, but the HttpConduitFeature is not being taken into account. So the timeout is the one by default of 1 minute, instead of the configured 10 seconds.

The only solution I see right now, is setting the HttpConduitFeature directly in the factory:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

factory.setAddress(soapConfigurations.getUrl());
factory.setBus(bus);
factory.getFeatures().add(conduitFeature());
```

Do I need some additional configuration, so the generated clients use the HttpConduitFeature defined in the Bus directly?

Answer (score 0):

**I managed it with below**

```
@Bean(name = "mltfClient")
  public Mltf mltf(MltfInMessageInterceptor in,MltfInMessageInterceptor out) {
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setServiceClass(Mltf.class);
    factoryBean.setAddress(address);      
    factoryBean.getOutInterceptors().add(out);
    factoryBean.getInInterceptors().add(in); 
    
    return (Mltf) factoryBean.create();  

  }
  @Bean HTTPConduit conduit(Mltf mtlf)
  {
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(mtlf);
    HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    policy.setReceiveTimeout(30000);
    policy.setConnectionTimeout(10000);
    policy.setConnection(ConnectionType.CLOSE);
    policy.setAllowChunking(false);
    HTTPConduit conduit=(HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    conduit.setClient(policy);
    return conduit;
  }
```